# Cups-Browsed Not Installed

Tags: printing, hp

Please help if you can. I'm unable to print. Ubuntu 20.04. Under Printer State there is the following: Stopped - No destination host name supplied by cups-browsed for printer "HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8030_series_6BAD1D_", is cups-browsed running?

I tried sudo apt-get purge --autoremove cups-browsed but got the return of cups-browsed is not installed.

I'm something of a novice to this. Please help if you can.

Comment: Have you tried installing it?  `sudo apt install cups-browsed`

Comment: Thank you, Terrance. I had, but this time it added a new printer-actually the same with a numerical "suffix" that works. I had already installed a new OS on a different partition to do my work, but this is a much neater solution.

Comment: This worked, until it didn't. I tried the sequence again and nothing. I was so frustrated I did a clean install to the most recent Ubuntu, but the problem exists there, too. I've tried uninstalling the printer, it reinstalls immediately. I'm at wits end. I cannot afford to be without a printer.

Comment: If CUPS is installed right, you should be able to go to http://localhost:631/ and then to the Administration tab next to home above and add your printer that way.  CUPS is actually a very nice way to add printers since it is a universal way to install a lot of printers.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is what I have in the Printer State box:  Idle - No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed. I was informed by a Linux professional that this is not uncommon right now. I was printing just fine up until a couple of weeks ago.